# eBay api: Local pick up

Tags: c#, ebay-api

I am a .Net developer trying to list a product on eBay that is Click & Collect. My code snippet is :

```
Dim ServiceOption As New ShippingServiceOptionsType() 
ebayItem.ShippingDetails = New ShippingDetailsType() ebayItem.ShippingDetails.ShippingServiceOptions = New ShippingServiceOptionsTypeCollection() 
ServiceOption.ShippingService = "PickUpDropOff" 
ebayItem.AutoPay = True 
ebayItem.PickupInStoreDetails = New PickupInStoreDetailsType() ebayItem.PickupInStoreDetails.EligibleForPickupDropOff = True ebayItem.ShippingDetails.ShippingServiceOptions.Add(ServiceOption)
ebayItem.PickupInStoreDetails.EligibleForPickupInStore = True
ebayItem.PickupInStoreDetails.EligibleForPickupInStoreSpecified = True
```

I am getting error message-

> Postage service Click & Collect(370) is not available.One or more parameter values in the input request are invalid. Check the response for ErrorParameters elements to determine which parameters have invalid values. Correct these values, and then resend the input request."

Does anyone know what is missing in my code?

Comment: Ammendment: Title: eBay api: Click & Collect

Comment: Have you *Check(ed) the response for ErrorParameters elements to determine which parameters have invalid values*?